# C# converting value for each column into array

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq

I want to convert a C# object or datatable such that, each column becomes a key & values becomes a array

```
year    productOne     ProductTwo      ProductThree
2010    1              2                 3
2011    10             20                30
2012    100            200               300
2013    1000           2000              3000
```

I am looking to generate following JSON output. Please keep in mind, no of rows and columns are dynamic.

```
[{
    name: productOne ,
    data: [1,10,100,1000]
},{
    name: productTwo ,
    data: [2,20,200,2000]
},{
    name: productThree ,
    data: [3,30,300,3000]
}]
```

Comment: And where and how is that data stored?

Comment: how is it stored - not sorted (ps - dont say 'in a database' - what c# data structure is it in)

Comment: @pm100: As i mentioned in my questions, data can be stored in list of C# object or a datatable.

Comment: @JleruOHeP: I don't know why, but I kept reading it as `sorted` and not `stored` :(

Comment: and what do the c# objects look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("col1");
            dt.Columns.Add("col2");
            dt.Columns.Add("col3");

            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "10";
            dr[1] = "20";
            dr[2] = "30";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "100";
            dr[1] = "200";
            dr[2] = "300";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "1000";
            dr[1] = "2000";
            dr[2] = "3000";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();
                result.name = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                result.data = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                               .Select(row => row[i])
                               .ToArray();
                list.Add(result);
            }

            var op = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

Comment: @pm100: I don't understand. What is the issue here?

Comment: becuase your result is hard coded- he says "Please keep in mind, no of rows and columns are dynamic.".

Comment: @pm100 Please correct me if I am wrong but this solution is dynamic. It will grow based on no of rows and columns available in datatable. I am just using datatable as source.

Comment: @OpenStack `i` is the count index of Columns, if `dt` has one more row, then `row[i]` won't retrieve all the vertical cells in a column into array.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this with help of Lists and Dictionaries.

```
public static IDictionary<string, List<object>> TransposeDataTable(DataTable table)
{

    if (table == null) {
        return null;
    }

    var dicData = new Dictionary<string, List<object>> ();
    var lstRows = new List<object>[table.Columns.Count];

    foreach (DataRow item in table.Rows) {
        for (var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++) {
            if (lstRows [i] == null) {
                lstRows [i] = new List<object> ();
            }
            lstRows [i].Add (item [i]); 
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++) {
        dicData.Add (table.Columns [i].ColumnName, lstRows [i]);
    }

    return dicData;
}
```

Code above will create keys for dictionary from Column names of tables and data for each column will go into corresponding list. It's sort of tuple.

Let's assume your `DataTable` is a valid `dt`

```
var dataObject = TransposeDataTable (dt);
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (dataObject, Formatting.Indented);
```

After successful conversion, `jsonString` will contain our good looking Json object. In my case, `dt` as dummy data so will produce something like.

```
{
    "year": [
        "2010",
        "2011",
        "2012",
        "2013",
        "2014"
    ],
    "produceOne": [
        "1",
        "11",
        "21",
        "31",
        "41"
    ],
    "ProductTwo": [
        "2",
        "12",
        "22",
        "32",
        "42"
    ],
    "ProductThree": [
        "3",
        "13",
        "23",
        "33",
        "43"
    ]
}
```